# "In spite of" vs. "despite"

Tags: word-choice, formal-language, formality, register

Which one is more formal and suitable for an academic context?

> 1. Despite being elected to office, she remains first and foremost a writer.
> 2. In spite of being elected to office, she remains first and foremost a writer.

Comment: [Lawless English](https://www.lawlessenglish.com/english-mistakes/despite-vs-in-spite-of/#:~:text=The%20English%20terms%20despite%20and,just%20the%20single%20word%20despite.) says ***despite** might be a tiny bit more formal*, but that's just an opinion (which I don't particularly agree with anyway).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is basically a matter of style. Ngram says that, since about 1940, “despite” has become more common in published works than “in spite of.” In terms of personal style, I don’t pay much attention to recent trends in mere popularity, but that is a purely personal opinion.

“Despite” does fit with the modern criterion of brevity better than “in spite of,” a criterion that I have generally adopted. So I would likely choose “despite” unless I was avoiding repetition. But again this is personal opinion about style, not a rule.